# Saber mas de un número mínimo python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como hago para calcular los dos numero mas pequeños de un arreglo?
usar un min solo me sirve para saber el mas pequeño no los dos mas pequeño

```
    def minimo(a):
     mini=a[0]
    for m in range (len(n)):
       if a[m]<mini: 
           mini=a[m]
    return mini
```

Comment: y si usas 2 min?

Comment: o ya que sabes un array, usas un array de minimos del largo que queres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que no sea obvio aunque sea más sencillo de lo que parece, solo tienes que ordenar la lista de menor a mayor y los dos primeros elementos son los dos "mínimos".

Ejemplo de código:

```py
a=[4,5,3,-6,2,3,1]

s=sorted(a)

print(s[:2])

# Salida
# [-6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución funciona para cualquier cantidad de "mínimos" que quieras pedir:

```
def min2(lista, num):
    minimos = [lista[0]]
    for x in lista[1:]:
        if x < minimos[-1] or len(minimos) < num:
            minimos.append(x)
    return minimos[-num:]
```

La idea es tener una lista `minimos` donde ir guardando cada mínimo que se vaya encontrando. Un mínimo es un nuevo valor menor que el último registrado en `minimos`.

Al terminar de procesar la lista de entrada, sólo nos queda retornar los últimos valores en la lista `minimos`.

#### Demo

```
def min2(lista, num):
    minimos = [lista[0]]
    for x in lista[1:]:
        if x < minimos[-1] or len(minimos) < num:
            minimos.append(x)
    return minimos[-num:]

tests = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,2],
    [1],
    [0]
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, min2(test, 2))
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] [1, 2]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] [2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [1, 1]
[1, 2] [1, 2]
[1] [1]
[0] [0]
```

Process finished with exit code 0